# grep - group by matched word

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Say I have a log file with Exceptions:

```
NoReceiveTaskException
NullPointerException
InvalidArgumentException
etc
```

How can I grep grouped by the matched word so that each Exception appears only once in the result ?

Sample output :

```
grep Exception error.log

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
doInTransaction       190 | NoReceiveTaskException
doInTransaction       190 | NoReceiveTaskException
doInTransaction       190 | NoReceiveTaskException
```

Comment: Do you have a sample output?

Comment: Question updated with sample output.

Comment: grep Exception error.log | sort | uniq Did you mean this ?

Comment: @Patrick85 `sort -u` will do the `uniq` part for you, though if you want a count of how often each shows up `sort | uniq -c` can help

Comment: And your input file is representative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use awk for this

```
awk '/Exception/{l[$0]}END{for(e in l){print e}}' error.log
```